# Extract last url component NGINX

Tags: nginx

In my config file, I need to extract the last part of a url into a variable for use in a redirect e.g. if the url is http://www.example.com/question, I need "question" so that I can set up a rewrite. How can I do this please?

Comment: Using appropriate regexp of cource

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved as follows:

```
if ($request_uri ~* "([^/]*$)" ) {
  set  $last_path_component  $1;
}
```

You can then use the $last_path_component var anywhere you wish. Note this regex will return everything after the last / which could include in url arguments, so if you do not need them, you will have to modify the regex above accordingly.